# What is the GNOME equivalent of Unity scopes?

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-shell

I recently switched from Unity to GNOME. I've noticed that when performing a search in GNOME Shell, the results include apps, documents, contacts and more, similar to scopes in Unity. What are these "scopes" called in GNOME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are simply called "search providers" in GNOME. This is implemented by applications providing a DBus based *SearchProvider* API, and registering as providers with gnome-shell via files to specify the DBus name and endpoint, and the app's .desktop file ID.

You can read more at https://developer.gnome.org/SearchProvider/

Comment: Open *Settings* and navigate to *Search* to find the search providers installed for your GNOME system.